# Android unit test onclick method

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I want to test the behaviour of my android activity when a button is clicked. The onclick method will instantiate a new object internally. Based on interactions with the object (involving interaction with a web server) the button should set text in a text view.

I'd like to mock the object so that I can test each possible response and verify that the correct UI text has been set.

My question is, how can I inject the mock? The signature of the onclick method is specified directly by android, so that can't be changed, and I can't inject the object via the constructor, as it is an activity launched when the application opens.

Any ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...
        // The object I want to mock
        Request request = new Request();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 public void onClick(View view) {
   fooBar();
 }
}
public void fooBar(){
  ...
    // The object I want to mock
    Request request = //injected Mock ;
    ...
}
```